# How do I play a video file in Javafx? -> Sample code

Tags: video, javafx, javafx-8, media-player

I am trying to play a video (format doesn´t matter - I have converted it to flv, mov and mp4) in a simple javafx application. I just want to play the video in a window.

The sample code below already works fine - but only with a URL Video from the oracle Website. I cannot make it work with a local file on my computer, even if I give the Media object a File with location.

How do I need to modify the code to make a file in my project folder play?

Here´s the code:

```
package Video;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class player extends Application{

StackPane stack = new StackPane();



public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

Media media = new 
Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-
2.flv");

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);


primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(new MediaView(player)), 540, 
208));
primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
primaryStage.show();

player.play();
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Application.launch();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//declare the media player and file to have class scope
 final File file = new File("x.mp4");
    final String MEDIA_URL = file.toURI().toString();

    // Create a Media
    final Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);

    // Create a Media Player
    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

This will look for a file in the same directory as your java file.